# Error 1004 in Excel, when try to assign variable to the cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined
when I run macro on worksheet "Sierpien 2017" it is ok, but in worksheet "Wrzesien 2017" I get error when it should write the results to the cells. Below I put a fragment of macro code, the rest is for other months.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Prowizja_kwartal()
Dim rng, rng1, rng2, kom, MyRng, MyRng1, MyRng2, wrzesienRange As Range
Dim a, b  As Integer
Dim prowizja, prowizja1, prowizja2, targety, targety1, targety2, procent, procent1, procent2 As Long
Dim szukana, Miesiac As String
Dim yourPassword As String
yourPassword = "1111"
szukana = "TARGET"
Miesiac = Cells(1, 19).Value
'Sierpień
    ElseIf Miesiac = "Sierpień" Then
    Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
    Set rng = Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Range("A1:M200")
    For Each kom In rng
        If kom.Value Like szukana Then
            a = kom.Row
            b = kom.Column
            targety = Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Cells(a, b + 1).Value
            prowizja = Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Cells(a - 2, b + 1).Value
        End If
    Next
    Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Protect Password:=yourPassword
    Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
    Set rng1 = Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Range("A1:M200")
    For Each kom In rng1
        If kom.Value Like szukana Then
            a = kom.Row
            b = kom.Column
            targety1 = Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a, b + 1).Value
            prowizja1 = Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a - 2, b + 1).Value
            Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 1).Value = targety1
            Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 1).Value = targety
            On Error Resume Next
                If prowizja1 > targety1 Then
                    If prowizja < targety Then
                        If (prowizja1 - (targety - prowizja)) >= targety1 Then
                        Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = (prowizja1 - (targety - prowizja)) / targety1
                        Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = (prowizja + (targety - prowizja)) / targety
                        Else
                        Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja1 / targety1
                        Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = prowizja / targety
                        End If
                    Else
                    Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja1 / targety1
                    Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = prowizja / targety
                    End If
                ElseIf prowizja1 < targety1 Then
                    If prowizja > targety Then
                        If (prowizja - (targety1 - prowizja1)) >= targety Then
                        Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = (prowizja1 + (targety1 - prowizja1)) / targety1
                        Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = (prowizja - (targety1 - prowizja1)) / targety
                        Else
                        Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja1 / targety1
                        Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = prowizja / targety
                        End If
                    Else
                    Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja1 / targety1
                    Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = prowizja / targety
                    End If
                Else
                Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja1 / targety1
                Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = prowizja / targety
                End If
            On Error Resume Next
        End If
    Next
    Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Protect Password:=yourPassword
'Wrzesień
    ElseIf Miesiac = "Wrzesień" Then
    Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
    Set rng = Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Range("A1:M200")
    For Each kom In rng
        If kom.Value Like szukana Then
            a = kom.Row
            b = kom.Column
            targety = Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Cells(a, b + 1).Value
            prowizja = Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Cells(a - 2, b + 1).Value
        End If
    Next
    Sheets("Lipiec 2017").Protect Password:=yourPassword
    Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
    Set rng1 = Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Range("A1:M200")
    For Each kom In rng1
        If kom.Value Like szukana Then
            a = kom.Row
            b = kom.Column
            targety1 = Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a, b + 1).Value
            prowizja1 = Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a - 2, b + 1).Value
            procent = Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value
            procent1 = Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value
         End If
    Next
    Sheets("Sierpień 2017").Protect Password:=yourPassword
    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
    Set rng2 = Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Range("A1:M200")
    For Each kom In rng2
        If kom.Value Like szukana Then
            a = kom.Row
            b = kom.Column
            targety2 = Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a, b + 1).Value
            prowizja2 = Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a - 2, b + 1).Value
            Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 9, b + 1).Value = (targety + targety1 + targety2)
            Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 1).Value = (targety2)
            Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 1).Value = (targety1)
            Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 1).Value = (targety)
            Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 9, b + 2).Value = (prowizja + prowizja1 + prowizja2) / (targety + targety1 + targety2)
            If procent >= 1 Then
                If procent1 >= 1 Then
                    If prowizja2 >= targety2 Then
                            Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja2 / targety2
                            Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1
                            Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = procent
                    Else
                            If (prowizja + prowizja1) > (targety + targety1) Then
                                If ((prowizja + prowizja1) - (targety2 - prowizja2)) >= (targety + targety1) Then
                                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = (prowizja2 + (targety2 - prowizja2)) / targety2
                                    If procent1 >= procent Then
                                        If (prowizja1 - (targety2 - prowizja2)) >= targety1 Then
                                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = (prowizja1 - (targety2 - prowizja2)) / targety1
                                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = procent
                                        Else
                                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = (prowizja1 + prowizja2 + prowizja) / (targety + targety1 + targety2)
                                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = targety / targety
                                        End If
                                    Else
                                        If (prowizja - (targety2 - prowizja2)) >= targety Then
                                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1
                                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = (prowizja - (targety2 - prowizja2)) / targety
                                        Else
                                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = targety1 / targety1
                                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = (prowizja1 + prowizja2 + prowizja) / (targety + targety1 + targety2)
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja2 / targety2
                                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1
                                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = procent
                                End If
                            Else
                                Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja2 / targety2
                                Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1
                                Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = procent
                            End If
                    End If
                Else
                If prowizja2 >= targety2 Then
                    If (prowizja2 - (targety1 - prowizja1)) >= targety2 Then
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = (prowizja2 - (targety1 - prowizja1)) / targety2
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = (prowizja1 + (targety1 - prowizja1)) / targety1
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = procent
                    Else
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja2 / targety2
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = procent
                    End If
                Else
                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja2 / targety2
                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1
                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = procent
                End If
                End If
            Else
                If prowizja2 >= targety2 Then
                    If (prowizja2 - (targety - prowizja)) >= targety2 Then
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = (prowizja2 - (targety - prowizja)) / targety2
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = (prowizja + (targety - prowizja)) / targety
                    Else
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja2 / targety2
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1
                        Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = procent
                    End If
                Else
                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja2 / targety2
                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1
                    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 8, b + 2).Value = procent
                End If
            End If
        End If
        'On Error Resume Next
    Next
    Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Protect Password:=yourPassword
```

Please help me to find what is wrong.

Regards
Greg

Comment: You will make it much easier for us to help you if you tell us which line of the code is giving the error.  (Trying to access row number -1 **may** be the issue, but it is hard to tell.)

Comment: It is getting after 
                   ' If prowizja2 >= targety2 Then '
                     in lineslike this:
                           ' Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja2 / targety2'
depend which one condition is fulfilled

Comment: (a) Which of those two lines does it crash on?  Or do you mean it actually crashes on the line after those two, i.e. on the line `Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 7, b + 2).Value = procent1`?
  (b) What are the values a of `a`, `b`, `prowizja2`, `targety2` and `procent1` when it crashes?

Comment: this line `Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Cells(a + 6, b + 2).Value = prowizja2 / targety2`

Comment: What are the values of `a` and `b` when it crashes?

Comment: `a=7`, `b=13`, `prowizja2 = 100000`, `targety=100000`, `procent1 = 100%`

Comment: A 1004 error on that line implies accessing an invalid row/column, but `7+6` would be a valid row and `13+2` would be a valid column.  I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: Oh - wait - I think you would also get it if the cell was protected.  Are you sure you used the correct password in `Sheets("Wrzesień 2017").Unprotect Password:=yourPassword`?

Comment: Yes, me too and in other sheets this was working in similar values. Is it possible that it crashes becouse of other module with the same variuables `a` and `b` ? //pasword is ok

Comment: You have declared `a` and `b` to be local to the current procedure.  (You declared `b` as an `Integer` and `a` as a `Variant`, which isn't a good idea, but it shouldn't matter too much.)  Unless you were passing those variables `ByRef` to another subroutine, they should be fine.  (And I can't see any calls to other procedures anywhere in your code between where you set the values and where you use the values.)

Comment: Are you sure the password on that sheet is the same as on other sheets?  Try entering a value manually into cell `O13` and see what happens.

Comment: Interestingly, earlier in your code you have some `On Error Resume Next` statements which never get disabled with an `On Error GoTo 0`.  I assume the program logic must never have reached those lines or else you wouldn't be receiving any sort of error message at all.

Comment: All I can suggest now is that you fix the declarations so that you don't use so many `Variant` variable types - `Variant` variables can mask a lot of errors at the time that the real issue occurs, and cause errors later on.  So change statements like `Dim rng, rng1, rng2, kom, MyRng, MyRng1, MyRng2, wrzesienRange As Range` to `Dim rng As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, kom As Range, MyRng As Range, MyRng1 As Range, MyRng2 As Range, wrzesienRange As Range` (assuming that's what you intended) and see if an error comes up earlier.

Comment: Thanks for help, I solved it. I had an another macro on Worksheet Change and this causing the problem, It was insomuch strange that didnt get an error in other sheets before with the same macros.